# Are there edge cases for checking if a string is null?

Tags: c#

I recently took ownership of some code from an author that is no longer with the company.
Throughout the code I'm finding this line

```
if (string.Compare(string.Empty, textbox1.Text, true) == 0)
```

I'm not the most advanced C# programmer, but to me that seems functionally the same as

```
if (textbox1.Text == "")
```

Is there any edge case that the first line will catch that the second one won't?

Comment: For that case, no, you can (and should) use the second form.  Additionally, you are not checking for null, you are checking for an empty string only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **comparing string ignoring case**, but its a bad way of doing it. `String.Equals` has an overload for comparing strings with ignoring case.

To check if string consist of empty string, [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be used, if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher and you want to consider space as empty string then you can use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

If you only want to compare the value with empty string then `textbox1.Text == ""` or `textbox1.Text == string.Empty` is enough.

Comment: His question is - will string.Empty, specifically, ever have different behavior whether you check for it case-sensitively or not. Which, I don't know for *sure* that it doesn't, but I'm pretty confident it doesn't.

Comment: @neminem, yes on an empty string, case insensitive comparison doesn't make any sense. I only wanted to highlight what exactly is being tried with `string.Compare`.

Comment: The question was more specifically aimed at the string.Compare vs the other check. I have NO idea why the previous guy added in the case insensitivity bit.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you should use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

As pointed out in the comments, [`String.IsNullOrWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is especially useful since you're working with GUI controls, which often may contain just whitespace, and not actually be an "empty" string.

Comment: Also String.IsNullOrWhitespace(textbox1.Text) will handle times when its full of spaces / tab characters.

Comment: You should point out to the OP that he is confusing the empty string with null.